# Challenging integration problem of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration

While preparing a tutorial session for my students, I come across a very challenging integration, which is :$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t^2 }\  \mathrm{d}t$$

I attempted many methods to solve it but with no use.
Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do $\int t e^{t^2} dt$.

Comment: Depends on how you interpret $\int$. If it means $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, then this is a well-known result. If you looking for an antiderivative, then your tutorial session is not good...

Comment: Thank you for our response . well it is integration from - infinity to + infinity ! what is the well-know result you referred to ? by the way it is tutorial on linear system analysis

Comment: Then you should add those bounds in your integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Relation_to_the_gamma_function

Comment: Great !  This is what I was looking for , thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the antiderivative of $e^{t^{2}}$: $$\int e^{t^2 }\  \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname{erfi}(x),$$where $\operatorname{erfi}(x)$ is the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) defined as $$\operatorname{erfi}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}\mathrm{d}t.$$  There is no way of expressing the antiderivative of $e^{t^{2}}$ in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Brilliant !!! wow you are a calculus genius . Thank you so much .

Comment: From where can learn such advance calculus ? I should be grateful if you would recommend a resource to me .

Comment: Honestly the wikipedia page is a pretty good start if you just want some of the terminology.  Error functions are just one of many types of [special functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions).

Comment: luckily I found a video on YouTube that solves the same problem .But he uses erf(x) function instead ! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkytxdedxhU

Comment: Careful!  That video solves $\int e^{-t^2}\,dt$, not $\int e^{t^2}\,dt$.  The minus sign makes a difference.  Though, we can write $\operatorname{erfi}(x) = -i\operatorname{erf}(ix)$, so if you want to express your integral in terms of the error function it would be written $-\frac{i\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname{erf}(ix)$

Comment: Well noted . many thanks